# Encore Vue.js style compilation wrong folder

Tags: symfony, vue.js, sass, vue-component, webpack-encore

I'm running on Symfony 4.1 with Webpack Encore, Vue.js app for frontend and SCSS styles. In VUE single file component I declare style that gets compiled however into public/build/js/ folder as app.css together with app/js in same folder. Any idea how can I change destination to public/build/css/app.css where I have all my sccs files compiled together into a single file? This is achieved by import, however I fail to set what I have described above.
Here is part of my webpack.config.js:

```
 .enableSassLoader()
 .enableVueLoader()
 .addEntry('js/app', './assets/js/app.js')
 .addStyleEntry('css/app', './assets/css/main.scss')
```

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to achieve what you want is by configuring your webpack.config.js like this:

```
.enableSassLoader()
.enableVueLoader()
.configureFilenames({
    css: 'css/[name].css',
    js: 'js/[name].js'
})
.addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
```

Then in your `assets/js/app.js` file:

```
require('../scss/main.scss');
// your code
```

The above configuration will produce a `build/js/app.js` file and a `build/css/app.css` file (all your scss files compiled together into a single file).

Comment: Thank you for your effort, however this emmited compilation error: https://ibb.co/kh92nU

Comment: It doesn't seem related with the setup I proposed